# CraftyJS how to calculate vector between 2 sprites?

Tags: javascript, math, vector, angle

I am a noob in game programming and not so good at Maths, I am trying to write a 1945 style shooting game, all been good so far but I am in a bottle neck that I cannot figure out how to make enemy aim at the player.

Lets say I have enemy sprite and player sprite, how do I find out the angle and the path? This sounds like calculating vector between 2 points, I have been reading the documentation and particularly this link http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-math-Vector2D.html

I just cannot figure out how to do it, I have tried the following

```
var enemyV = Crafty.math.Vector2D(enemy.x, enemy.y);
var playerV = Crafty.math.Vector2D(player.x, player.y);
var angle = enemyV.angleTo(playerV);
```

The value of angle is always between -3 to 3, which doesn't seem the right angles at all.

I hope someone who has CraftyJS experience can help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angleTo` function returns radian value, so running this will give the actual angle degreex `Crafty.math.radToDeg(radianValue)`

To aim the player and make the bullet travel at that direction you just get the difference between 2 points
`bullet.x - player.x'`bullet.y - player.y' then apply a incremental rate such as below (

```
bullet.x_diff = (target.x - bullet.x)*0.02;
bullet.y_diff = (target.y - bullet.y)*0.02;
```

then inside enterframe loop:

```
this.x += this.x_diff;
this.y += this.y_diff;
```

Once you get the idea, you should normalize your diff by dividing by the distance between the points.